# Green line in grease pencil (not from Onion Skinning)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil

I am working with grease pencil and have the strange green lines as seen below that only appear when going into rendered mode AND there is a light shinning on the grease pencil object. Otherwise, the line is black. I have tried:

1. Using Eevee, Cycles, and Octane.
2. Blender 2.93
3. Blender 3.0
4. Changing the Onion Skinning colors.
5. Going forwards and backwards in the timeline.
6. Looked for an option for multisampling based on other posts, couldn't find the option.
7. Rendering with GPU and CPU. No change from either.

Does anyone know what the green line is being caused by and how to get it to show as the intended color when in render mode?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:
I somehow had used vertex paint and painted those areas. No idea how... but, I'll leave this up for anyone else who does the same.